How to verify the user by biometric on resume with MAUI
In my NET8 MAUI application, I added the biometric authentication for the login using Plugin.Fingerprint. It is working. Now, I'm trying to protect the access to the application on resume.
For that, I added the following code in the App.xaml.cs:
protected override async void OnResume()
{
    var isAvailable = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);

    if (isAvailable)
    {
        var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration(
                                 "Login using biometrics", 
                                 "Confirm login with your biometrics");
        request.AllowAlternativeAuthentication = true;

        var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request);

        Console.Write(result);
    }
}

When I resume the application from the background, the authentication starts and never stops. I have to close the app to stop the request.

You have to call it from the UI thread:
var result = await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(
       async () => await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request));

Edit
You may also use MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync() as @Julian's comment  suggested .
Which one to choose in your case?

For Dotnet Maui, what the difference between Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async()) and MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync.
Which is better MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() VS Dispatcher.Dispatch()


In MAUI, you would typically use MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync() for this.

@Julian I have tried yours but faced the same issue as the op, seems the action is not exectued on ui thread  for some reason, could you confirm ?.The one which is obsolete is Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action) if used you get a warning "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action) is obsolete: 'Use BindableObject.Dispatcher.Dispatch() instead.

I use the same plugin in one of my apps and it works with MainThread. You need to use the one I linked, which takes a Func<Task<T>> and returns a Task<T>, specifically: var result = await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () => await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request));

@Julian they both have same input and output types, I have linked an answer explaining their differences.

Well, I guess "it depends". Code-behind usually runs on the UI Thread (in most cases that's the MainThread in MAUI, as stated in the answer you linked). Now, if you call the above code from within the code-behind, you wouldn't even need to use the Dispatcher or MainThread, unless you want to play it safe or are running on Windows. If calling the code from a ViewModel, the MainThread would be the go-to choice, as the ViewModel shouldn't have any knowledge of the View it's associated with (doing otherwise would be a violation of the MVVM pattern). Or you could inject the IDispatcher.

@Enrico if it answers your question, please mark it as accepted ✔ thanks.
